# ASP .NET Label orientation for East Asian Text

Tags: asp.net, text, internationalization, orientation, label

Does anyone know how to create an asp .net label control that is orientated in 90 degrees clockwise

Right now the way I do it is using 
 tag like this

```
<td style="font-size: 13px; width: 20px; 
           text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom;">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="日" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text="本" /><br />
    ・<br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server" Text="学" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl4" runat="server" Text="校" />
</td>
```

Is there a way to do this in just one Label? Like using a orientation property?

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="日本・学校" orientation="90degress" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout-flow : vertical-ideographic

Comment: style="...; ...; layout-flow: vertical-ideographic;"

Comment: This seems to only work on IE. It does not work for latest firefox and chrome. Any other tweeks suggestion to make this cross browser?